# Import an html file's in oracle 10g

Tags: html, oracle, oracle10g

Is possible import an html file in oracle 10g and do search in it a word?
How must I proceed?

Comment: It sounds like you want [Oracle Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Text)?

Comment: Yes, but i don't understans how import an external html file

Comment: Just [RTFM](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/aload.htm#CCREF2257)

Comment: it is possible but it sound complex, please refer the link  
 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14217/query.htm

Answer (score 1):

Why would you involve Oracle into searching a HTML file for some *string*?

- double-click that file
- it'll open in a browser
- CTRL + F will open search so ... search for that *word*

or even

- open HTML file in any text editor
- use its search capabilities to locate that *word*

If you insist on Oracle, then

- create a table
- one of its columns should be CLOB
- load HTML file into it using

  - Oracle Text (as suggested by @paulsm4)
  - SQL*Loader, or
  - external table feature, or
  - UTL_FILE, or
  - DBMS_LOB, or perhaps something else
- use DBMS_LOB.INSTR function against that CLOB column and see whether the *word* exists within it

---

What I'm trying to say is: I don't think that Oracle (as a *database management system*) is the right *tool* to do that. The fact that it can be done doesn't mean that it *should* be done. There are other (programming) languages that are designed to do that in a simple(r) manner. For example, Python.

On the other hand, I kind of *understand* that - when / if Oracle is the only tool you know - it is the tool you're going to use.

Comment: Q: Why would you involve Oracle into searching a HTML file for some string?   A: To efficiently search for text (or maybe even a "text pattern") among many rows.  Perhaps programmatically (not just manually).  And without the overhead of opening a file at a time in a browser.  NOTE: Using DBMS_LOB.INSTR is actually a good idea, as a workaround.  But Oracle Text is arguably the "best" solution.

Comment: @paulsm4, thank you for the comment. I edited my *ranting answer* a little bit by a) adding Oracle Text as an option (which you've already mentioned when commenting the question), and b) saying a few more words about the whole thing. Now - going *virtually* to Albert Park and, hopefully, enjoy today's F1 race.

Comment: I must use oracle text for this problem.
I'm trying the example FILE_DATASTORE Example of this link: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/cdatadic.htm#CCREF1923
I executed these instructions:

    begin
        ctx_ddl.create_preference('COMMON_DIR','FILE_DATASTORE');
        ctx_ddl.set_attribute('COMMON_DIR','PATH','/mydocs');
   end;

If I don't wrong, mydocs will be the directory where the files must be placed.
But, where is mydocs' directory on my file system?

Comment: Should be on the database server, I presume.

Comment: But, if i run the command dir /s mydocs by the system command line, it doesn't found any directory

Comment: If you are following instructions written in documentation, you probably don't have the same directories on your system as they have.

Comment: I executed these instuctions:
[link](https://pastebin.com/ja5EwadD)[/link]
Seem who I've solved.
Do you think same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
FUNCTION GetFile(FolderName IN VARCHAR2, FileName IN VARCHAR2) RETURN CLOB IS

    xbfile   BFILE; 
    xclob    CLOB; 
    destOffset INTEGER := 1; 
    srcOffset INTEGER := 1; 
    warning INTEGER;
    lang_context INTEGER;

BEGIN 
    xbfile := BFILENAME (FolderName, FileName); 
    DBMS_LOB.OPEN (xbfile); 
    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(xblob, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.SESSION);    
    DBMS_LOB.LOADCLOBFROMFILE(
        dest_lob => xblob, 
        src_bfile => xbfile, 
        amount => DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(xbfile), 
        dest_offset => destOffset, 
        src_offset => srcOffset,
        bfile_csid => NLS_CHARSET_ID('AL32UTF8'),
        lang_context => lang_context,
        warning => warning); 

    DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(xbfile); 

    RETURN xclob; 

END GetFile;
```